# Augment Python cmd module "help" printout

Tags: python

I am using Python's `cmd` module to create a custom interactive prompt for an application. Right now, when I type `help` at the prompt, it auto-displays a list of my custom commands, e.g.

```
[myPromt] help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
cmd1 cmd2 cmd3
```

I would like to augment this with some text explaining keyboard shortcuts that can be used at the prompt, e.g.

```
[myPromt] help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
cmd1 cmd2 cmd3

(use Ctrl+l to clear screen, Ctrl+a to move cursor to line start, Ctrl+e to move cursor to line end)
```

Does anyone know a way to tool-in and modify the boiler-plate text that gets printed when issuing the help command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`doc_header` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.doc_header):

```
import cmd

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_cmd1(self): pass
    def do_cmd2(self): pass
    def do_cmd3(self): pass

d = MyCmd()
d.doc_header = '(use Ctrl+l to clear screen, Ctrl+a ...)'  # <---
d.cmdloop()
```

Sample output:

```
(Cmd) ?

(use Ctrl+l to clear screen, Ctrl+a ...)
========================================
help

Undocumented commands:
======================
cmd1  cmd2  cmd3
```

---

If you need to put the custom message after the normal help messages, use `do_help`:

```
import cmd

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_cmd1(self): pass
    def do_cmd2(self): pass
    def do_cmd3(self): pass
    def do_help(self, *args):
        cmd.Cmd.do_help(self, *args)
        print 'use Ctrl+l to clear screen, Ctrl+a ...)'

d = MyCmd()
d.cmdloop()
```

output:

```
(Cmd) ?

Undocumented commands:
======================
cmd1  cmd2  cmd3  help

use Ctrl+l to clear screen, Ctrl+a ...)
```

Comment: Perfect. I used the do_help() override, and it worked like a charm, thanks!